# Visual Studio Database Not Updating

Tags: c#, webforms

I am working on a school project and for some reason my mysql database doesn't update despite no of row changed is more than 0 and triggering the Update sucessful alert. It also manage to only update my image data from my fileupload.

```
**admin_products_details_edit.aspx.cs**

protected void btn_ProdEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int result = 0;
            string image = "";

            if (FileUpload_ProdImg.HasFile == true)
            {
                image = "images\\" + FileUpload_ProdImg.FileName;
                img_result.ImageUrl = FileUpload_ProdImg.FileName;
            }
            else 
            {
                image = img_result.ImageUrl;
            }
            
            Product Prod = new Product();
            string datProdID = lbl_ProdID.Text;
            string datProdName = tb_ProdName.Text;
            string datProdDesc = tb_ProdDesc.Text;
            string datProdImg = img_result.ImageUrl;
            decimal datProdPrice = decimal.Parse(tb_ProdPrice.Text);
            int datProdCal = int.Parse(tb_ProdCal.Text);
            int datStockLvl = int.Parse(tb_StockLvl.Text);
            result = Prod.ProductUpdate(datProdID, datProdName, datProdDesc, datProdImg, datProdPrice, datProdCal, datStockLvl);
            if (result > 0)
            {
                string saveimg = Server.MapPath(" ") + "\\" + image;
                FileUpload_ProdImg.SaveAs(saveimg);
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Update successful');</script>");
                Response.Redirect("admin_products_details.aspx?ProdID=" + datProdID);

            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Update fail');</script>");
            }
        }<-The code for the button edit event trigger

**Product.cs**
    ...public int ProductUpdate(string upID, string upName, string upDesc, string upImg, decimal upPrice, int upCal, int upstkLvl)
        {
            string queryStr = "UPDATE Products SET" + " ProdName = @productName, " + " ProdDesc = @productDesc, " + " ProdImg = @productImage, " + " ProdPrice = @productPrice, " + " ProdCalorie = @productCal, " + " StockLevel = @productStkLvl " + " WHERE ProdID = @productID";

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productID", upID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productName", upName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productDesc", upDesc);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productImage", upImg);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productPrice", upPrice);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productCal", upCal);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productStkLvl", upstkLvl);

            conn.Open();

            int nofRow = 0;
            nofRow = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();

            return nofRow;
        }<-The code for updating the mysql database,located in a different cs file,titled Product.cs
```

My mysql database table is called Products

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the `btn_ProdEdit_Click` method and check the values the `Prod` variable has. They may be different from what you expect.

Comment: @Cleptus You're right. my variables that starts with dat all have the same values as my database table, even though I manually changed the textbox to a different value. Do you know how I could fixed this issue. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is that a webpage? Are you setting those textboxes on the page load event? If so, you should remember That the `Page_Load` is triggered on every load, and that happens also when the load is caused because of a button postback.

Comment: @LeeZhengJie, based on my test, the code works well. If you input all the same values that already exists the database, the result also returned 1. Therefore, I want to confirm what do you input about  Product. I suggest that it will be better for you to upload a gif image here to analyze your problem.

Comment: @Cleptus, I just recently found out about the Page_Load and it might be the actual issue. I will code the button to prevent it from always reloading the page and tell you the result.

Comment: @Jack J Jun ,My teacher and I spent a while finding out the issue, our hypothesis is that the button refreshes the page.I am now testing if the hypothesis is true. Also thank you and Cleptus for helping me.I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Cleptus, you and my teacher are both right! I used !Ispostback and it works now. Thank you for helping me for the past few days.

Comment: @Jack J Jun, my problem has been solved. I used !Ispostback. Thank you for helping me.